# Cookie set without a name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, cookies

I'm trying to set a simple cookie but the name of the cookie is never set.

I'm setting the cookie like this:

```
document.cookie = `${process.env.REACT_APP_TERMS_CONDITIONS_ACCEPTANCE_NAME}=true;path=/`;
```

The name of the cookie is not set, only content is set with the name + the value. The environment variable is defined properly since it's displayed in the "content".

Why isn't `${process.env.REACT_APP_TERMS_CONDITIONS_ACCEPTANCE_NAME}` defined as the name and "true" as the content? I'm doing exacly the same thing for other cookies and it's working.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.
An extra "=" character was defined on environment variable creation. So on cookie creation, I had `=name=value` instead of "name=value" which resulted on the creation of a cookie without a name.

Comment: Where's the extra "=" character? I can't seem to find any mistake.

Comment: The "=" was in the environment variable itself.